# how to set background of grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, bitmapimage, imagebrush

I have a `BitmapImage`, and want to set it as `Background` of `Grid`. I have tried this

xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="imgBg" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

c#:

```
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.DecodePixelWidth =(int) scrnWidth;
        bmp.DecodePixelHeight = (int)scrnHeight;
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

        ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = bmp };
        imgBg.ImageSource = ib.ImageSource;
```

**Output:** Output is just black.

**Question:** using above code I am unable to set `bitmapimage` as `background` of `Grid` element, Am I missing something ?

**Update** I knew, it works fine when we set `image` as `background` to `grid` like:

```
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = bmp };
ContentPanel.Background = ib;
```

But I need to use `xaml` way, Question is same.

Comment: Is there some special reason why you are using a bitmapImage?

Comment: just because it takes less memory and allow to scale down the size of image. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6b8d2d70-b372-486d-92b0-c09556d6a5a4/how-to-clear-memory-used-by-writeablebitmapimage?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: I've tested this code and it works as is, properly setting the background of the grid. The problem must be somewhere else - the layout of the grid (its children cover it completely)?

Comment: @lisp have you tested as contentpanel.background=bmp ?, have a look at updated question

Comment: i've tested the first two code fragments. it worked for a picture from PhotoChooserTask.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="None" 
                    ImageSource="Your Path/source" 
                    AlignmentY="Center" 
                    AlignmentX="Center" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

This might help you, cant promise you it will but try it. was found on this post.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749245/adjust-the-size-of-a-xaml-grid-background-image)

Comment: I am picking image from photoChooserTask, So can't use that

Comment: Ahh okay, that i didnt get from the post, my bad. Give me a sec ill look into it.